# Getting Invalid hook call error on importing a component in React

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-thunk

I have built a login page where on filling the username and password and hitting the submit button, it dispatches the action which basically goes to the backend and checks whether the username and password is valid. I am using `React` and `redux` and this is my login page below

**login.js (simplified)**

```
import LoginHandle from '../login/LoginHandle'

function userLogin(event) {
  event.preventDefault()
  const username = document.getElementById("username").value
  const password = document.getElementById("password").value
  
  LoginHandle(username, password)

}

const Login = () => {
  return (
    <div className="flex-row align-items-center">
                  <form onSubmit={(e) => userLogin(e)}>
                    <h1>Login</h1>
                    
                      <input id="username" type="email" placeholder="Username" required/>
                 
                      <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
      
                        <button type="submit" className="px-4">Login</button>
                </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

**LoginHandle.js (simplified)**

```
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import {getLoginStatus} from '../actions/loginAction'


const LoginHandle = (username, password) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    dispatch(getLoginStatus(username, password))
    const loginState = useSelector(state=> state.loginStatus) 

    if(loginState.loading) {
        console.log("please wait")
    }

    // .... rest of the logic
}

export default LoginHandle
```

As you can see I try to dispatch the action and then check the state to get confirmation from the backend. But I get this error

`Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:...`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hooks are made for use in functional components. You are calling them in a simple function, that's not allowed and what the error means.

Comment: @nil Hi nil, Yes I wanted to separate out the processing of login details in a separate file instead of doing it inside `Login` component itself. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import {getLoginStatus} from '../actions/loginAction'

const useLoginHandler = (username, password, submitted) => {
     const dispatch = useDispatch();
     const loginState = useSelector(state=> state.loginStatus)
     // it is better to put the dispatch inside a useEffect rather than outside
     useEffect(() => {
        if(!submitted) {return};
        dispatch(getLoginStatus(username, password))
     }, [username, password, submitted]);


    if(loginState.loading) {
        console.log("please wait")
    }

    // .... rest of the logic
}

export default useLoginHandler
```

And your usage of the hook is wrong. it should not be inside a callback function.
it should be at the top level. Something like below. Also you should not access dom elements directly, instead use useRef or useState to get value

```
const Login = () => {
   const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
   const [password, setPassword] = useState('')
   const [submitted, setSubmitted] = useState(false);
   useLoginHandler(username, password, submitted); //custom hook should be used at this level
   return (
      <form onSubmit={(e) => setSubmitted(true)}>
      <input id="username" type="email" placeholder="Username" required onChange={e => setUsername(e.target.value)}/>
          </form>   
   )
}
```

Comment: hi Ravi, thanks for your reply. This is what I was looking for and custom hook is the answer. I will accept this. You also mentioned that Dom elements shouldn't be directly accessed. May I know what's wrong with that approach?

Comment: sometimes the actual dom element might not be available by the time you do that query. in this case it might work, but in general it is better to use useRef for accessing DOM

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2 hooks in this implementation `useDispatch` & `useSelector` and calling them inside a function, which is invalid usage. Hooks can only be called inside a **functional component**. So changing your above implementation as below should work:

**Login.js**

```
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux'
import {getLoginStatus} from '../actions/loginAction'

const Login = () => {
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
  const loginState = useSelector(state=> state.loginStatus) 

  function userLogin(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const username = document.getElementById("username").value
    const password = document.getElementById("password").value
  
    dispatch(getLoginStatus(username, password))
  }


  return (
    <div className="flex-row align-items-center">
                  <form onSubmit={(e) => userLogin(e)}>
                    <h1>Login</h1>
                    
                      <input id="username" type="email" placeholder="Username" required/>
                 
                      <input id="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" required/>
      
                        <button type="submit" className="px-4">{loginState.loading ? "Please wait..." : "Login"}</button>
                </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Login
```

Things to note:

- Called useDispatch directly in functional component and not inside a function of functional component. Then we can use the result of useDispatch inside a function
- Called useSelector inside functional component and then used the output to show loading in place of text in the button

Comment: Hi Hashir, thanks for your reply. Yes I am aware that I can call inside the `Login` component and it would work. But I wanted to separate out the processing of login details in a separate file. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes that's possible. We usually handle all the processing inside redux actions and reduces and then dispatch those actions directly in functional component. We cannot call useDispatch outside functional component. 
So just implement your login logic via redux reducers/actions and the dispatch the login action from this component.

Comment: I do have a reducer and action and in fact the function `getLoginStatus` is actually imported from a redux action where it makes the api call to the backend. I just wanted to separate out the form validation and and post api actions in a separate file.

Comment: I recommend taking a look into some articles using hooks and redux so you can get better idea about how its implemented. This is basically the standard way (and I guess the only possible way) of using hooks and redux.